# Get value in display field Ext JS 5

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I want to output what is in my display field to the console.

```
 var getValue = Ext.getCmp('fieldID').getValue();

//That doesn't seem to be getting anything, tips?
```

Comment: You need to provide some sort of context. What does "getting anything" mean? What is the component with the id `fieldID`?

Comment: if its a id, then use Ext.getcmp('fieldID'), If its a itemId, then Ext.getcmp('#fieldID')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tmp` here is the Id of the field I used in the main page

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
     var value = Ext.getCmp('tmp').getValue();
     alert("value");
});
```